# Как сделать данную структуру?

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка

Привет, подскажите если возможно без jS сделать такой блок. Внимательно прошу обратить внимания на элементы, их количество разделяются ровно на 2 и они слева и справа. Решение требуется универсальное что бы любое количество делала такой вид. Или без JS никак? Если никак подскажите примерный алгоритм создания

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Разделить на отдельные колонки не вариант?

Comment: Это будет выводится из админ панели

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
     -moz-column-count: 2;
          column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list_item">Пункт 1</li>
  <li class="list_item">Пункт 2</li>
  <li class="list_item">Пункт 3</li>
  <li class="list_item">Пункт 4</li>
  <li class="list_item">Пункт 5</li>
  <li class="list_item">Пункт 6</li>
  <li class="list_item">Пункт 7</li>
  <li class="list_item">Пункт 8</li>
  <li class="list_item">Пункт 9</li>
  <li class="list_item">Пункт 10</li>
  <li class="list_item">Пункт 11</li>
  <li class="list_item">Пункт 12</li>
  <li class="list_item">Пункт 13</li>
  <li class="list_item">Пункт 14</li>
</ul>
```